# Need help defining an arc

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to form similar arcs (like the blue one) to join points X-Z, and A-B at both ends of the line BX in the following picture.

XY and YZ are unknown but equal.

How do I find the radius of the arc and the exact position of BX relative to the rest of the shape?

[image]

Comment: Is this what you want? Trace the line through $Z$ perpendicular to $YZ$ and the line through $X$ perpendicular to $XY$. Consider the intersection of these two lines call it $O$. Then draw the circle with center at $O$ and radius $OX=OZ$.

Comment: That is close, but assumes I know the absolute position of BX, which I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t = XY = YZ = AC=BC$ (where $C$ is the intersection of the vertical and slanted lines near $A$ and $B$).  Let $D$ be the intersection of the horizontal and vertical lines at top left.  Thus $CDY$ is a $45$ degree right triangle with hypotenuse $30+2t$ and legs $30-t$, so $30+2t = \sqrt{2} (30 - t)$.  Solve for $t$.

The centre of arc $AB$ is then a point $P$ such that $ACP$ and $BCP$ are congruent right triangles, with angle $APC$ of $22.5^\circ $ .  Thus $AP = t \cot(22.5 ^\circ)$.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for. A question though: Are ACP and BCP actually right triangles? Wouldn't P be slightly closer to C than the line AB needed to form right triangles? (Either way will be close enough for my purposes.)